# Trouble installing venv python 2.7.12

Tags: python, installation

I am currently learning Flask and to do so I have to install `virtualenv`. It installs it normally but after that I have to activate the environment. In the tutorial it says that I have to type this into CMD: 
venv\scripts\activate

It gives me the error: `"The system cannot find the path specified`".

I tried to run this and it doesn't work either:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What are the steps you followed to install your virtualenv? Also, where did it install it? If it did install it as `venv`, did you make sure that the directory you are in actually has that `venv` directory? Maybe it installed the virtualenv under a different name? Details are required here.

Comment: @idjaw I have no idea where it is installed. I followed this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_environment.htm

Comment: The tutorial says to put in: `venv\scripts\activate`. That's not what you have. I think casing is important here.

Comment: @idjaw Still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you at this point. The error is clearly indicating that it can't find the right path. Check where you are trying to run that command from, and ensure you are in the right location.

Comment: You should also make sure that whatever commands you were running before in fact worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure where your working directory of your project is,lets say you have your `venv` in a directory called `FolderX`. Go to the directory's location, hold `shift` and right click on it then click on "Open terminal here" from the right click option.Now that you have `terminal/cmd` opened in that directory, type in `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` or `venv\Scripts\activate`. Do make sure that you have `activate.py` or `activate.bat` in the specific path.

You can also try this if not installed:

```
 pip install virtualenv
```

If you have it installed,create another virtual environment for the project.Type these in your terminal:

```
cd my_project_folder
virtualenv venv
venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: I did what you said but for some reason, in the folder there is no activate.py nor activate.bat.

Comment: That's why your getting the error.You dont have venv installed or configured properly.

Comment: This is really odd... I have all of the files except that activate file. I have done exactly like the tutorial said to do. These are the files that I currently have: easy_install, easy_install-2.7, pip, pip2.7, pip2, virtualenv. Is there any way I can get the activate file itself?

Comment: Type in virtualenv venv in the terminal that was opened in your working directory.

Comment: Then venv/bin/activate since the first command would create a venv