# Activating Venv In Python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have been trying to install Virtual Environments on my newly installed python on windows and am getting this prompt:

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\dell pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
```

How do I activate it, if virtualenv is already installed?

Comment: Have you read the usr guide? https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble installing venv python 2.7.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693401/trouble-installing-venv-python-2-7-12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to install the virtualenv package, which it looks like you've done. The second step is to create a new virtual environment, and the third step is to activate it. I don't have a windows machine to test this.

So first step done

Second step would be to create a new virtual environment, could look something like this:

```
virtualenv my_folder
```

Then the third step would be to activate it like this

```
my_folder\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up cmd, navigate to your project's folder with `cd` and write

```
virtualenv venv
venv\Scripts\activate
```

This will create a new venv for your given project and activate it

once you are done use `deactivate` to quit venv

Answer (score -1):

use below command:

```
python -m venv <your virtual environment name>
```