# How do I activate venv in Python?

Tags: python, python-venv

I've created a virtual env (my-ve) and it works fine from the terminal.
But why it's so difficult to activate venv from python?
Python 3.10, Ubuntu 22.04

Thanks

```
> python3 -m venv my-ve # OK: my-ve created from terminal

exec("'myfolder/my-ve/bin/activate'")  # python: no errors but my-ve is not activated

t1="python3 code24.py"  #  my-ve must be activated for code24.py to run  
subprocess.call(t1 , shell=True)  # it fails  

subprocess.call("source myfolder/my-ve/bin/activate", shell=True)  # /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

source myfolder/my-ve/bin/activate  # it works only from terminal
```

I've seen few posts but none worked:

[Activating Venv In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616104/activating-venv-in-python)

[Getting a 'source: not found' error when using source in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670191/getting-a-source-not-found-error-when-using-source-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Can you try `subprocess.call('myfolder/my-ve/bin/python code24.py' , shell=True)` ?

Comment: Why would you need to? A venv has a different Python interpreter. It is quite impossible to move a running script or a session from one interpreter to another. You can only replace your interpreter with a fresh one, forgetting everything you have done in the session so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by using Popen, no need to call source /my/ve/activate from python.

```
subprocess.Popen(path/toscript/in/ve/)
```